# Bash - change the filename by changing the filename variable

Tags: bash, filenames

I want to save the results of a multiple grep in a .txt format. I do

```
for i in GO_*.txt; do
    grep -o "GO:\w*" ${i} | grep -f - ../PFAM2GO.txt > ${i}_PFAM+GO.txt
done
```

The thing is that, obviously, the final filename comprehends the original file extension too, being `GO_*.txt_PFAM+GO.txt`.
Now, I'd like to only have `GO_*_PFAM+GO.txt`. Is there a way to modify the `${i}` as to cancel the `.txt` without having to perform a `rename` or a `mv` afterwards?

**Note:** the `*` part has variable length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [*parameter expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to remove the extension from the filename:

```
for i in GO_*.txt; do
    name="${i%.txt}"
    grep -o "GO:\w*" "${i}" | grep -f - ../PFAM2GO.txt > "${name}_PFAM+GO.txt"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick! The link you shared was very useful, too.